# Set text before and after selected value javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to insert values before and after the selected text.I found this code in the other answers but it doesnt work on firefox.Is there any workaround it?

```
function insertHtmlAtSelectionEnd(html, isBefore) {
var sel, range, node;
if (window.getSelection) {
    sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
        range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        range.collapse(isBefore);

        // Range.createContextualFragment() would be useful here but was
        // until recently non-standard and not supported in all browsers
        // (IE9, for one)
        var el = document.createElement("div");
        el.innerHTML = html;
        var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(), node, lastNode;
        while ( (node = el.firstChild) ) {
            lastNode = frag.appendChild(node);
        }
        range.insertNode(frag);
    }
} else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
    range = document.selection.createRange();
    range.collapse(isBefore);
    range.pasteHTML(html);
}
}
```

In this code when the range.collapse is set to true it remains true throughout if we try to set it to false.This only happens in firefox.Works perfectly in chrome.Any workarounds?

Comment: Just use append prepend functions

Comment: you should use document if you want this to work in firefox

Comment: `toStart: A boolean value: true collapses the Range to its start, false to its end. If omitted, it defaults to false .` https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/range/collapse

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I have checked the documentation but it doesnt revert back to false.You can check

Comment: If omitted the parameter, it turns to false. Do you try it?

Comment: yup tried it already